# How can I select specific sibling of an element in table?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, cypress

I am pointing to the middle table cell and I can able to get text of the next cell using the `next()` method but when I tried to use `parent()` I am getting full row text which is three cells. Below is the HTML code. Kindly help.

```
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(2)').each((e1, index) => {
  const course = e1.text()
  
  if (course.includes('Python')) {
    cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(2)').eq(index).parent()
        .then((price) => {
      const courseprice = price.text()
      // expect(courseprice).to.be.equal('25')
      cy.log(courseprice)
    })
  }
})
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My question is to get the text(Rahul Shetty) in first column by finding a text (Python) in second column. Also I can able to grab the text(25) which is in third column by using next() but can't get correct solution by using parent(). Please note I am not trying to assert the text, I need to get the text. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

For the **first row** containing "Python", `.contains(selector, text)` is the shortest and `.next()` gives you the price column.

```js
cy.contains('[name="courses"] tbody tr td:nth-child(2)', 'Python') // first match
  .prev()                                             // move left one cell
  .invoke('text')
  .as('instructor')

cy.get('@instructor').then(instructorName => {   // "Rahul Shetty"
  ...
})
```

For **multiple rows** containing "Python", change to the pseudo-selector `:contains()`

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] tbody tr td:nth-child(2):contains("Python")')   // all matches
  .prev()
  .then($instructors => {
    const names = [...$instructors].map(el => el.innerText)
    cy.wrap(names).as('instructors')
  })

cy.get('@instructor').then(instructorName => {   // ["Rahul Shetty", ...]
  ...
})
```

Comment: Hi Fody, the first solution is giving full column which means I am getting text for all the rows and result is Rahul Shetty Rahul Shetty Rahul..........

Comment: Let me check it again - I tested `.next()` when I thought you needed the Price, that was ok.

Comment: I only get a single result. If you use `cy.contains()` it's only possible to get one result - as per the docs [contains() Single Element](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Single-Element).

Comment: You might still be using a `cy.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the text is the entire text is that it combines the text of all child elements. To avoid this, we can take a few different routes:

First solution: we can just check if the parent contains the value:

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(2)')
  .eq(index)
  .parent()
  .should('contain.text', 25);
```

Second solution: grab the third row TD directly

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(3)') // nth-child is index-1
  .should('have.text', 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

After using `parent`, you can use `within` to go inside the parent `tr` and access each `td` elements like this:

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(2)')
  .eq(index)
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('td').eq(0).should('have.text', 'Rahul Shetty')
    cy.get('td')
      .eq(1)
      .should(
        'have.text',
        'Master Selenium Automation is simple Python Language'
      )
    cy.get('td').eq(2).should('have.text', '25')
  })
```

You can reach the first `td` based on the second `td` like this:

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Master Selenium Automation is simple Python Language')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('td').eq(0).should('have.text', 'Rahul Shetty')
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for assertion and also it seems parent() is missing before within(). But I am trying to get the text of first <td> by pointing to second <td>.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to iterate over the rows and check the 2nd  instead of iterating over the 2nd  and then travers up and down the DOM to get the price and then use [`cypress-if`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if)

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr')
  .should("have.length.greaterThan", 0)
  .each($row =>{
    cy.wrap($row)
      .contains("td", "Python", { timeout: 0 })
      .if("visible")
      .then(() => {
        cy.log("Price of Python course");
        cy.wrap($row).contains("td", "25").should("be.visible");
      })
      .else()
      .log("Instructor does NOT sell Python");
   }
})
```

Here is a minimal reproducible [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/checkPriceIfMatchingTextTable.md).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, and my preferred way is to use `find` I would also recommend not using `then` or or other nested function like `each` if you don't need it. And even though you can use jquery selectors like `nth-child()`, using the `eq()` makes it a bit more readable (IMHO). Also `nth-child` index is not 0-based but 1-based, so `nth-child(2)` returns the 2nd column, not the 3rd.

for example, this will give you the 8th row and 3rd column

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr')
  .eq(7)
  .find('td')
  .eq(2)
```

if I repeat anything more than twice in a test, I tend to write helper functions in the spec.

```js
// define somewhere at the beginning of the file (or add to commands.js)
const getTableCell(r,c) => cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr')
  .eq(r)
  .find('td')
  .eq(c)

describe('‍♂️', () => {
  it('', () => {
    getTableCell(0,0).should('have.text', 'Instructor')
    getTableCell(0,1).should('have.text', 'Course')
    getTableCell(0,2).should('have.text', 'Price')
    getTableCell(1,0).should('have.text', 'Rahul Shetty')
    getTableCell(1,1).should('contain.text', 'Appium')
    getTableCell(1,2).should('have.text', '25')
    // etc...
  })
})
```

in some cases, depending on your html markup, the text might be padded with white space. In that case you might want to use `contain.text` instead of `have.text` but that could also cause issues, eg. `125` would match `contain.text("25")`.

---

another option

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr') // select all rows
  .contains("Python") // find 1st matched row
  .find("td") // find all columns in row
  .eq(2) // pick 3rd column
  .should("have.text", "25")  // make asserion
```

---

Additionally, you can use `find` if you want to find a child element from a selector. In this case I added `.find('td').eq(2)`. But note that this example shows a really convoluted way to search up and down the DOM.

```js
cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(2)').each((e1, index)=>{
        const course = e1.text()
        if(course.includes('Python')){
            cy.get('[name="courses"] > tbody >tr >td:nth-child(2)').eq(index).parent().find('td').eq(2).then((price)=>{
                const courseprice = price.text()
                // expect(courseprice).to.be.equal('25')
                cy.log(courseprice)
            })
        }
    })
```